# DISTINCT clause with WHERE

Tags: sql, distinct, where-clause

How can I use the DISTINCT clause with WHERE? For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DISTINCT email; -- email is a column name
```

I want to select all columns from a table with distinct email addresses.

Comment: That's contradiction in terms. Do you mean "SELECTing all columns whose email is unique"?

Comment: see updated query means I have updated my query in my answer that solves your problem.

Comment: I believe the question is : how do you filter out all the rows but one for each email. So if the table has 100 rows but only 10 unique emails among them I want to select 10 rows.

Answer (score 46):

If you mean all columns whose email is unique:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE email in
     (SELECT email FROM table GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(email)=1);
```

Comment: is it wrong if I write `SELECT * FROM table where email in(select distinct email from table)` ?

Comment: @jWeaver...Even I was thinking initially what you were thinking. But, tried executing the query. It is wrong.

Comment: @Delfino a `GROUP BY` partitions the result set based on the email string, and applies the `HAVING` as a sort of to decide which partitions to return. Only partitions with a single row in them, i.e. unique mails, are returned by the subquery.

Answer (score 6):

May be by :

```
SELECT DISTINCT email,id FROM table where id='2';
```

Comment: @Mohit: what do you wanna say? elaborate please?

Comment: i want to select all rows having unique email and having id='2';

Comment: email and id are two columns in my table

Comment: i don't want to update, i just want to select the rows from my table !! with unique email and having id='2';

for example : - 

SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DISTINCT (email) AND id='2';

I know the above query is wrong but i just want to do something as in above query

Comment: @Mohit: see updated query means I have updated my query in my answer that solves your problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
select t1.*
from YourTable as t1
  inner join
    (select email
     from YourTable
     group by email
     having count(email) = 1 ) as t2
    on t1.email = t2.email
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

`SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY email`

- This returns all rows with a unique email taken by the first ID appearance (if that makes sense)
- I assume this is what you were looking since I had about the same question but none of these answers worked for me.

Comment: This will work only if the only column in table is [email]  as only columns from GROUP BY conditions or aggregations may be in SELECT list

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab_name
GROUP BY email_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER(). You can specify where conditions as well. (e.g. `Name LIKE'MyName%` in the following query)

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (SELECT ID, Name, Email,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber
     FROM   MyTable
     WHERE  Name LIKE 'MyName%') AS a
WHERE   a.RowNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple query will do it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
GROUP BY email 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Comment: The op did not specify the flavor of SQL, but this command will not run in SQL Server and produces ambiguous results in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work:

```
 SELECT email FROM table1 t1 
          where UNIQUE(SELECT * FROM table1 t2);
```

Comment: I'm not aware of many DBMS' that have implemented the UNIQUE predicate. Which one are you using? Also, I think you got the queries backwards: shouldn't `SELECT email` be wrapped in the `UNIQUE()` predicate? And I think you need some kind of join clause (`FROM table1 t2 WHERE t2.email = t1.email`).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique column in your table (e.g. tableid) then try this.

```
SELECT EMAIL FROM TABLE WHERE TABLEID IN 
(SELECT MAX(TABLEID), EMAIL FROM TABLE GROUP BY EMAIL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as to what you are trying to achieve (probably due to my non english background) but I'll try to answer all the possible cases

### **1. Select all tuples from X table provided it has no duplicate email values**

Using `UNIQUE` in the `WHERE` clause

***This is not widely implemented so it may not work on certain database flavors***

(SQLite, postgreSQL do not support it, not sure about the rest)

---

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE UNIQUE (
    SELECT email
    FROM table
);
```

Without the `UNIQUE` operator

---

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    (
        SELECT email 
        FROM table
    ) EXCEPT ALL (
        SELECT DISTINCT email
        FROM table
    )
);
```

### **2. Select all email values that are unique to the table relation**

Query 1 in style of our previous query

---

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE email NOT IN (
    (
        SELECT email
        FROM table 
    ) EXCEPT ALL ( 
        SELECT DISTINCT email
        FROM table
);
```

Another version of this query is the one offered by [@Adam Matan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51197/adam-matan)

---

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE email IN (
    SELECT email 
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY email 
    HAVING COUNT(email) = 1
);
```

### **3. Select all emails into a 1 column relation without any duplicates for further processing in a parent query**

---

( reason I came across this post :3 )

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT email
    FROM table
)
```

Answer (score -3):

Query:

```
Select *, (Select distinct email) from Table1
```

Answer (score -3):

SELECT  DISTINCT dbo.Table.Email,dbo.Table.FirstName dbo.Table.LastName, dbo.Table.DateOfBirth (etc) FROM   dbo.Table.Contacts
WHERE   Email = 'name@email';