# How to use DISTINCT in WHERE CLAUSE to avoid repeated row returns

Tags: mysql, sql

The result of this SQL query should return a set of 6 rows.

```
SELECT baseFeeds.siteURL, feedFinishes.timeTaken, feedFinishes.timeSubmitted 
FROM feedFinishes 
LEFT OUTER JOIN baseFeeds 
ON feedFinishes.GUID = baseFeeds.GUID 
WHERE feedFinishes.nowDate = baseFeeds.nowDate 
AND baseFeeds.siteURL LIKE '%www.example.com%'
```

Currently it returns 18 rows, the correct 6 rows are being repeated 3 times. I figure a solution to this is to have another WHERE clause something similar to:

`WHERE DISTINCT feedFinishes.ID`

After researching this I have tried:

```
SELECT baseFeeds.siteURL, feedFinishes.timeTaken, feedFinishes.timeSubmitted 
FROM feedFinishes 
JOIN baseFeeds 
ON feedFinishes.GUID = baseFeeds.GUID 
WHERE baseFeeds.siteURL LIKE '%www.example.com%' AND feedFinishes.ID in
     (SELECT ID FROM feedFinishes GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(ID)=1);
```

After the discussion found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610528/distinct-clause-with-where)

Alas, this still returns 18 rows. I believe the answer is similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `select *` is never good. What columns do you really need being returned?

Comment: baseFeeds.siteURL, feedFinishes.timeTaken, feedFinishes.timeSubmitted

I have updated the question to account for this

Comment: Does `select distinct baseFeeds.siteURL, feedFinishes.timeTaken, feedFinishes.timeSubmitted from ...` work for you with the first query? And change the `left join` to an `inner join`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Still returns 18 rows. The same 6 being repeated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should apply `group by` clause.

```
SELECT 
baseFeeds.siteURL, feedFinishes.timeTaken, feedFinishes.timeSubmitted
FROM feedFinishes 
JOIN baseFeeds 
ON feedFinishes.GUID = baseFeeds.GUID 
WHERE baseFeeds.siteURL LIKE '%www.example.com%' 
GROUP BY
baseFeeds.siteURL, feedFinishes.timeTaken, feedFinishes.timeSubmitted
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems I need to research GROUP BY more